# Is Rundeck able to execute distributed Jobs?

Tags: distributed, execution, rundeck

With respect to segmented LAN environments, i have to delegate job execution to remote Server-Systems. Is Rundeck able to delegate the execution of Jobs to other servers? If yes, is it possible to reach the target execution system by chaining a server-route (First connect server A, then Server B, and finally execute the job on Server C)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can set the order behavior on the "Nodes" tab (at the moment of creating or editing your job) and set the Rank Attribute & Rank Order values after set the Node Filter. e.g: you can set the node's names in the Rank Attribute and set "Descending" in the Rank Order.

Also, you can set any custom attribute in the "Rank Attribute" to follow any desired behavior.

More info [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/document-format-reference/job-v20.html#dispatch).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. As i understand, a "node" corresponds to a host system where i could run whatwever the job needs to execute. In our LAN infrastructure with 1000+ host systems, security is a big point. Is there any need to install an "agent" service, an https listener or something else on the nodes involved in the automation process?

Comment: Great. An agent isn't necessary, for SSH-based systems: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/howto/ssh-on-linux-nodes.html#using-ssh-on-linux-unix-nodes Windows-based systems: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/howto/configuring-windows-nodes.html#running-jobs-on-windows-nodes, if these nodes are running on AWS you can use the EC2 plugin: https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-ec2-nodes-plugin